# Cross reference between two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first one contains all the main data and each row is like:

```
timestamp|source_ip|destination_ip|number_packets|number_bytes|etc.
```

The second one contains a reference table for the IP addresses and the networks these addresses belong to:

```
network1|ip_address1
network1|ip_address2
network2|ip_address3
etc.|etc.
```

Possibly it may contain network addresses with submask like:

```
network3|ip_network/submask
```

So what is the best way for dataframe 1 to find the network for its address (e.g., `source_ip`) in dataframe 2? The reference table doesn't have to be a dataframe. Any data structure is OK, as long as it's easy to reference the info. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the two example DataFrames, and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this firstly you can store the mapping of `network` and `ip_address` in a dictionary:

```
mapping = { ip_address1: network1,
            ip_address2: network1,
            ip_address3: network2,
            ... }
```

And to find the `network` corresponding to each entry of `source_ip` from main dataframe, use this:

```
df['network'] = df['source_ip'].apply(lambda x: mapping[x])
```

This gives you additional column named `network` in main dataframe which we assume has name `df` having column `source_ip`.